# How to display on a textView all string values from an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, textview, display

I have a string that receives different values every second. I want to store all that values to an ArrayList. The problem is that when i'm trying to display all the values, the textView updates to the last value. Is it possible to display all the values;

I want to display the values like: 500, 400, 300, 200 ...

Here is my code,

```
// that string receive a different value every second
// String values returns to me an integer 
String values = stringbuilder.substring(item + 1, endOfLineIndex); 


ArrayList<String> allvalues = new ArrayList<>();
allvalues.add(values);

for (int i = 0; i < allvalues.size(); i++) {       
   textView.setText(String.valueOf(allvalues));
}
```

Comment: You can format your code by pressing the [format button](https://i.imgur.com/i4o6pBS.png) in the editor.

Comment: what are `item` and `mact`?

Comment: mact is wrong sorry, String.valueOf(allvalues) is the correct

Comment: don't look the item because i'm receiving some values from arduino, the meaning is the String values returns to me an integer every second

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to build a `String` that contains all of the Strings and then setting the `textView` to that. It would be something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < allvalues.size(); i++) {
    sb.append(allvalues.get(i) + ", ");
}
textView.setText(sb.toString());
```

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS**

It seems like `values` already contains the `String` you want to display. I'm not sure if you need to store any values in an `Array`/`ArrayList`. Here is some code that you may find helpful.

```
//Example values String based on OP's comments
String values = "100, 200, 300, 400, 500";
//If you need to store the values, this turns that String into a String[]
String[] valuesArray = values.split(", ");
//If you really want to store those values in an ArrayList instead of a regular Array, you can do this
ArrayList<String> valuesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(valuesArray));
//Sets the textView to display the text, since values already reflects what you want to display
textView.setText(values);
```

Comment: I've tested it and it keeps showing only the last value!

Comment: Well, you're only adding one `value` to your `allvalues` `ArrayList`. I don't think the problem is with the logic I've provided (or even that @Isael Merljak has provided). I think the issue is with how you build your `ArrayList`.

Comment: Yew i know the logic is correct. How i should build my ArrayList?

Comment: I think that depends on how you're getting your `String`. Honestly, this line confuses me a little bit: `String values = stringbuilder.substring(item + 1, endOfLineIndex);` because I don't know what `item` or `endOfLineIndex` is. What is the value of `values` after that line?

Comment: Every second I receive a different number

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comments. Let me know if that helps and if you need more of an explanation. The two lines involving the `valuesArray` and the `valuesArrayList` are not required to display your text by the way. I included them in case they get used later on in the code.

Comment: My basic problem is that the String values are not standard like "100, 200, 300, 400, 500", values refreshing every sec.

Comment: This feels a lot like an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)... I'm not entirely sure how to help you out any further. You need to post more code, specifically an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give more details about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

you want to concatenate a List of strings with a separator? is that it?

Perhaps you can try something like that.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    values.add("Hi");
    values.add("how");
    values.add("are");
    values.add("you?");
    values.add("i'm");
    values.add("fine");
    values.add("thanks :)");


    System.out.println(String.join(" - ", values));
}
```

This piece of code will output:

> Hi - how - are - you? - i'm - fine - thanks :)

Comment: i don't know what the value is and also i want to display it on a textview not on the system